# Distribution of absolute value of Elliptically Symmetric Random Variable

Tags: distributions, random-variable, elliptical-distribution

I am studying Elliptically Symmetric Distributions and someone recommended me *Symmetric Multivariate and Related Distributions by Fang (1990)*, which is the book I am reading for that purpose.

I know that if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $|X|$ follows a folded normal distribution. So, I wonder if there exists some generalization. For that, let $X\sim \operatorname{EC}_1(\mu,\sigma^2,\psi)$, what is the distribution of $|X|$?

I thought using PDF's definition of $X\sim \operatorname{EC}_1(\mu,\sigma^2,\psi)$:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma}\psi\left(\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\right)$$
But I think it is the wrong way. Do you know what is the distribution of $|X|$ to know what I should have to prove? Or if you know an article that talks about this, It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is still under active research, I am not aware of a generalization to elliptical distributions.

The latest article that I know of is [On Moments of Folded and Truncated Multivariate Normal Distributions](https://www.cesarerobotti.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/JCGS-KR.pdf), which states in the conclusion:

> Generalizing the results to multivariate elliptical distributions
> requires a lot more work. Although the product moments of multivariate
> elliptical distributions can be obtained from the product moments of
> multivariate normal distributions (see, for example, Berkane and
> Bentler (1986) and Maruyama and Seo (2003)), it is not clear how to
> obtain product moments of folded and truncated multivariate elliptical
> distributions. We leave this topic for future research.